# What is number of pairs of integers (m,n) satisfying $m^2+mn+n^2=1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Question from Indian Statistical Institute B.Math (Hons.) Admission Test :2005

The number of pairs of integers (m,n) satisfying $m^2+mn+n^2=1$ is
A) 2
B) 4
C) 6
D) 8

Answer (score 4):

If you remove the possibility of the pairs $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ then to have a solution we must have $mn<0$. So WLOG assume $n<0$ and set $n=-p$.

So the equation becomes $m^2+p^2-mp=1 \Longrightarrow (m-p)^2+mp=1$. This happens iff $m=p=1$. So we get two more solutions $(1,-1)$ and $(-1,1)$.

I changed the last part of answer after the comment of @AndroidFish.

Comment: I do not think this is correct. What about the situation of $(1,-1)$. Then we get $1^2 + -1 +(-1)^2=1$.  And we can swap these two $m$ and $n$. So we 4 solutions.

Comment: @AndroidFish, Yeah you are correct. So there are 4 solutions. 2 more for the equation $(m-p)^2+mp=1$. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Another hint: $|mn| \leq \max(m^2,n^2)$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: there are no $m=n$ solutions, then look at $\;m^3-n^3=m-n \;\iff\; m^3-m = n^3-n$.

Comment: Wish the downvoter had left a comment why.